# Fibeamer mathserif option

Tags: beamer, sans-serif, beamerposter

I'm using the fibeamer package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fibeamer) with fonts option, but this makes the math equations sans-serif. I would like to have my equations as in usual math articles (serif).

I tried the nofonts option but this messes up with the fonts for regular text. I tried `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` and `\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}` but seems to make no difference. Any suggestions? Thanks!